# Angular Change ditection - set change detection of all components that extend base class to OnPush

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

I have a `Base` class that is extended by some components.
I want to know if there is any way to change the `Base` class **only** and set change detection of all components (Base's child classes) to `OnPush`?